# There is no link to the (still active) election

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

The election's still going on: it doesn't end for another 20 hours. But there's no way to get to it without a direct link.

Shouldn't there be some link somewhere for those who haven't voted yet? Otherwise, what's the point of having it continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a system message set to expire at the end of the elections. ♪

Comment: Hm, the meta system message also has vanished. I take it the election was unexpectedly prolonged by one day through primaries and thus Community didn't update the meta banner properly? This could be a bug alright.

Comment: @badp Didn't even pay heed to that. I expected the main site one to vanish because with a 72 hour election period, a 48 hour message was destined to expire. Someone should probably reinstate the Meta one, then. I don't recall it being extended, at least.

Comment: I took care of the meta message.